# HttpClient request timed out -- how can I determine the reason?

Tags: c#, .net-core

If an `HttpClient GetAsync` times out, I will get an OperationCanceledException. Is there any way to determine where in the process it timed out? Was it able to establish a connection, was there a DNS problem, etc.?

Comment: Are there inner exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of **HttpClient**.
You have to overcome it by implementing a workaround.

Have a look on this:

https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient